# How do I return to my current dungeon level after activating a second town portal?

Tags: torchlight

I had reached a dungeon level around 10-15 floors down, when I returned to Torchlight (the town) via a Town Portal scroll and got a quest from the Trill-bot to kill a monster on level 3. Easy! I ran down to level 3, one-shotted the baddie and instead of clicking an Identify scroll I clicked a Town Portal scroll.
I was hoping it wouldn't overwrite my previous portal if I didn't use it, so I ran back to my original portal but it brought me back to level 3!

So have I really lost all my progress? Can I not easily return to the farthest level I've reached?

Comment: Town portals in such games (Diablo, Fate etc.) overwrite older casts, so I think you have to run down all the way again :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Mostly. The story-dungeon has waypoints every few levels which you can port directly to from town, but other than that, you're stuck.

Comment: :/ Boo. Would have at least liked a confirmation before overwriting!